# Jpa - How to "findBy" two columns while both of them have the same name

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Character-in-Category based Jpa relationship here:

```kotlin
// Character.kt
@Entity
class Character (
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    var name: String,   //This one

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "category_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
    var category: Category? = null,

    var gender: Gender? = null
): Serializable {
    enum class Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE, OTHER
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Category.kt
@Entity
class Category (
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    var name: String? = null,   //Also this one

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category") @JsonIgnore
    var characters: MutableSet<Character> = mutableSetOf()
) : Serializable
```

I have done some "findBy" queries by multiple columns before, but this is the first time that both of them have the same name and i suppose its not working because of that, how can i reach this without changing any of their property names?

```kotlin
// CharacterRepository.kt
@Repository
interface CharacterRepository : JpaRepository<Character, Long> {

    fun findByNameAndCategory_Name(name: String, categoryName: String): Character

}
```

Edit: What is not working is that `findBYNameAndCategory_Name`, always returning `Result must not be null` as a `EmptyResultDataAccessException` despite the data actually exists in database.

Comment: You can use `@Query` annotation on a method of the repository and write manually the jpql query

Comment: could you please clarify what do you mean by "not working"? what is the result of the query? or maybe it throws an exception?

Comment: Sure, there it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data follows the path from the root entity in the implements (`JpaRepository<Character, Long>`): this should work:

```
Optional<Character> findByNameAndCategoryName(String name, String categoryName)
```

I don't use Kotlin, so this is Java syntax, but the same should apply for Kotlin: the method name matters.